# Can C++20 range adaptors refine the range concept of underlying range?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

Consider the following simple range:

```
struct my_range {
  int* begin();
  int* end();
  const int* data();
};
```

Although this class has a `data()` member, according to the definition of `contiguous_range` in [[range.refinements]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.refinements#concept:contiguous_range):

```
template<class T>
  concept contiguous_­range =
    random_­access_­range<T> && contiguous_­iterator<iterator_t<T>> &&
    requires(T& t) {
      { ranges::data(t) } -> same_­as<add_pointer_t<range_reference_t<T>>>;
    };
```

`ranges::data(t)` will directly call the `my_range`'s member function `data()` and return `const int*`, but since `my_range::begin()` returns `int*`, this makes `add_pointer_t<range_reference_t<my_range>>` to be `int*`, so the last *requires-clause* is not satisfied, **so that `my_range` is not a `contiguous_range`**.

However, when I apply some range adaptors to `my_range`, **it can construct a `contiguous_range`** ([goldbot](https://godbolt.org/z/jjvzf3xaM)):

```
random_access_range auto r1 = my_range{};
static_assert(!contiguous_range<my_range>);
contiguous_range auto r2 = r1 | std::views::take(1);
```

This is because [`take_view`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.take.view) inherits [`view_interface`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ranges#view.interface), and the `view_interface::data()` only constrains the derived's iterator to be [`contiguous_iterator`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous#concept:contiguous_iterator).

Since `my_range::begin()` returns `int*` which models `contiguous_iterator`, so `view_interface::data()` is instantiated and returns `to_address(ranges::begin(derived))` which is `int*`, this makes both `take_view::data()` and `begin()` return `int*`, so `r2` satisfies the last *requires-clause* and models `contiguous_range`.

Here, the range adaptors seem to refine the range concept of the underlying range, that is, converting a `random_access_range` to a `contiguous_range`, which seems to be dangerous since it makes `ranges::data(r2)` can return a modifiable `int*` pointer:

```
std::same_as<const int*> auto d1 = r1.data();
std::same_as<int*> auto d2 = r2.data();
```

I don't know if this refinement is allowed? Can this be considered a defect of the standard?  Or is there something wrong with the definition of `my_range`?

Comment: "*I don't know if this refinement is allowed?*" Yes, you do know. You cited the standard which specifically allows it.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider this a defect. The iterator/range model treats iterators as the truth. Several kinds of ranges deliberately have more functionality than just being a pair of iterators of some kind. This is because said functionality is materially useful and users of a range of a particular kind should expect to be able to use it. But this also leaves open the possibility of defining an incoherent range: where the iterator concept is stronger than the range concept because the range lacks certain functionality expected of the iterator concept.

If someone creates an incoherent range type, any functionality that operates on such a range (views, but also algorithms) has 3 options:

1. Believe the iterators.
2. Believe the range.
3. Error out.

Now for algorithms, if the algorithm wants to use the `data` member, it makes sense that it will believe the range. That is where the member is after all.

But for a view, does it make sense to believe the range? Views don't store copies of ranges. After all, a range can be a container. They instead store and operate on iterators and sentinels. They therefore treat ranges as just a way to get an iterator/sentinel pair.

When a view defines itself as a particular range type, it therefore manufactures the ancillary functional of the range from what it stores: the iterator/sentinel pair. And most such things are pretty simple to manufacture. The `data` member of a `contiguous_range` can be manufactured by [using `std::to_address`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/to_address) (a requirement of being a `contiguous_iterator`) on the result of `begin()`.

So when given an incoherent range, it would actually be *harder* to filter such things out based on the original range type. Particularly in light of `view_interface`, which only sees the new view type, not the range it is built from.

After all, not all views are built from other ranges. `iota_view` is a view, but it isn't built from anything. But its iterators are random access; so too is its range. `single_view` is likewise not built from a "range"; it treats a single object as a single-element contiguous range. And `subrange` is built from an iterator/sentinel pair, not a range.

So either views built from other ranges would have to have their own special `view_interface`... or you create circumstances where views are just better than their original ranges. Or you error out.

It should also be noted that the current behavior is 100% *safe*. No code will be functionally broken by having a view be stronger than the range it was built from. After all, your not-quite-`contiguous_range` type still provides non-`const` access to the elements. The user just has to work a bit harder for it.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, +1. However, I think in such a case the range adaptors should trust the underlying range since it's a "range" adaptor, not an "iterator" adaptor. Taking `views::all(r1)` as an example, `ref_view<my_range>::data()` does not constrain the iterator to be `contiguous_iterator`, but constrains the underlying range to be `contiguous_range`, so `ref_view<my_range>` does not have a `data()`. However, it still models `contiguous_range` because its `begin()` returns `contiguous_iterator` (and `ranges::data()` will use it), and such range refine occurs.

Comment: @康桓瑋: `ref_view` is different because it specifically stores the *range* and gives you access to it. Most views don't store the range; they store iterators into the range.